# Nextjs Webhook from Monday.com not updating component

Tags: next.js, webhooks, monday.com

I'm trying to use monday.com's integration feature to send a webhook request to my nextjs application. I receive the data, when I move an element on a board, or update something on an element every time in my handler function which looks like this:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
     if (req.method === 'POST') {         
         const challenge = req.body.challenge;         
         // Respond to the challenge         
         res.status(200).json(req.body);     
     } else {
         res.status(405).end();     
     } 
}
```

The challenge was just a parameter from monday to verify the connection, but I'm scared to remove it. I have debugged it several times, and also use ngrok to access the application, since its only on localhost:3000 at the moment.

This whole code is located at: `/pages/api/webhook.js`

My component is at `/app/dashboard/monday/page.tsx` and looks as follows:

```
export default function Page() {
    return (
        <div className={"h-full w-full"}>
            <iframe src="url_to_my_board" width="1700" height="800" ></iframe>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My goal is to update this component, or rerender this component, whenever i receive something thru the webhook.

I tried using websockets, as in having a websocket in my handler to then send a message whenever I receive a webhook change. Didn't work.

I tried using context, but I forgot that context only works in react components. So this didn't work either.

There was also a totally desperate and dirty approach of reloading the page every second thru a setInterval in my component, this luckily did also not work.